# how can I send a param into websock connection using cowboy

Tags: erlang, websocket, cowboy

in cowboy websocket example
in toppage_handler.erl

```
    handle(Req, State) ->
      {Echo, Req2} = cowboy_req:qs_val(<<"echo">>, Req),
      {ok, Req, State}.
```

I want to get the param Echo into the following function

for example:

localhost:8080/?echo=123

in ws_handler.erl

```
    websocket_init(_TransportName, Req, _Opts) ->
         %%How can I use the Echo(123) here?
         erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"Hello!">>),
         {ok, Req, undefined_state}.
```

Comment: Have you tried calling `cowboy_req:qs_val(<<"echo">>, Req)` from the  websocket_init function? I would assume it works.

Comment: Johlo's right. Can't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: it doesn't work in websocket_init/3,and the processid in the two func is different

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is to use path bindings :

In your routes :

```
Dispatch = cowboy_router:compile([
    %% {HostMatch, list({PathMatch, Handler, Opts})}
    {'_', [{"/echo/:echo", my_handler, []}]}
]),
```

Then in your code :

```
{Echo, Req2} = cowboy_req(echo,Req)
```

It's best to do this in Websocket_handle because you will be able to send your response to the socket. In init, you will have to carry it in your state, like this :

```
websocket_init(_TransportName, Req, _Opts) ->
    {Echo, Req2} = cowboy_req:binding(echo,Req),
    erlang:start_timer(1000, self(), <<"Hello!">>),
    {ok, Req2, {Echo}}.

websocket_handle(_Frame, Req, {Echo}) ->
    {reply, {text, Echo}, Req, State}.
```

As websocket is designed to handle long term connections, i use bindings like this to support information like channels, user ids, etc. But not data like in "echo" because you will want to send multiple different texts to echo without closing and reopen a websocket connection each time just to change URL.

Comment: do not have the param echo,either

Comment: All i want to do is send a param into websocket in erlang, but how?

Comment: ok so i edited my answer with a technique that i actually use, so it works. If it doesn't, you will have to show more code of yours. cheers